# don't want to check a condition for 1st time?

Tags: c++

I know that if I don't want to check a condition in first iterate of a loop, I have to give a condition that will ignore first time iterate.

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){scan(......) if(i!=0 &&......){};}
```

But I want to know that is there any help in C/C++ language that the condition will be ignored the first time automatically?

Comment: You can do this with a `do { ... } while` loop, but I don't know how to do that in a `for` loop. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: actually i want to compare a input with previous one,,but as there is no previous input of 1st one so i want to ignore 1st input comparison.

Comment: @AbdurRahim There no way to do this 'automatically' (all the answers below misunderstand your question). What is wrong with your solution? You should be pleased you invented it, it's called programming.

Comment: More context might allow more useful answers. What is the condition (as code, not merely described) you want checked in the other iterations? How do you set the values used in this condition?

Comment: If the 0-case is different, you can do that before the loop and then start counting from 1.

Answer (score 4):

do-while loop is there for this purpose.

```
int i=0;
do{
   // what you want to do
   i++;
}while(i<10);
```

This loop will execute at least once at all conditions.

## Edit

In your case, it's better take one input before the loop starts or you could also use `if` statement to check for first loop.

```
last_input=get_input();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    new_input=get_input();
    // do what you want to do with them.
    last_input=new_input;
}
```

or

```
last_input=null;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   new_input=get_input();

   if(i>0){
      // do what you want to do with them.    
   }
   last_input=new_input
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `do-while` loop it comes handy for your case

```
do{

// statement..

}while(condition);`
```

this will work.

the statement will execute first then the condition will be checked

so in your case the first iteration will be executed then it will check the condition

[see this for more explaination](https://www.programtopia.net/cplusplus/docs/do-while-loop)

Comment: sorry,i think i failed to make you understand my problem. If there is a condition in the loop and i do't want to check the condition in first iteration what will i do,without giving condition to avoid 1st loop.

Comment: @AbdurRahim - it's you who is not understanding.   If you want a loop construct that does something (or doesn't do something) on the first time through, use a loop construct other than a `for` loop.     `do`-`while` is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Do-while loop is the way to go!
It executes your instructions first and then check trueness of the condition in order to loop.

```
do {
//your instructions
} while(condition )
```

For details refer https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do